# postgresql: multiply all entries by a fxed number

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql database and a table like this:

```sql
Column         |              Type              |
---------------+--------------------------------+--
id             | bigint                         |
amount         | numeric(8,2)                   |
```

More precisely, I have :

```
id   | amount  |
-----+---------+-
 509 | -100.00 |
 517 |  -10.50 |
 518 |   -7.40 |
```

I want to change the type of `amount` to `bigint`. Before doing that, I would like to multiply each entry by 100.

I tried to do this:
 `update entrees set amount = amount * 100;`

But I got these errors (I get them in French, translation is mine:)

```
ERROR:  numerical field exceeds limits 
DETAIL : A field with precision 6 and scale 2 must be rounded to a value that is absolutely inferior to 10^4.
```

My guess is that I need to change the type `numeric(6,2)` to something else before the multiplication.

Is that true? How do I multiply all entries into this field by 100?

Comment: Alter the table to change `amount` type to something like `numeric(18,2)` before you do the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this:

alter table table_name alter column amount type bigint;

UPDATE table_name SET amount = (amount * 100);

alter table table_name alter column amount type numeric(8,2);

Comment: I did otter way round: first alter table to numeric(8,2) , then multiply by 10 and finally alter table to integer.

Answer (score 1):

Safest way would be to:

1. add another column of type bigint,
2. use it to store the multiplied values
3. check if new values are what you need;
4. delete existing amount column
5. rename new column to amount

   ALTER TABLE entrees ADD COLUMN amount_int BIGINT;

   UPDATE entrees SET amount_int=amount*100;

   ALTER TABLE entrees DROP COLUMN amount;

   ALTER TABLE entrees RENAME COLUMN amount_int TO amount;

Comment: No need for an intermediate column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah, good point, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a single ALTER table:

```
alter table the_table
   alter amount type bigint using (amount * 100)::bigint;
```